# Troubleshooting R table function to create a more complete-looking table

Tags: r, formattable

I'm attempting to create a table of relative percentage values for answers to a questionnaire (answers are graded 1-5) for a total of 3 questions.

I'm using the `formattable` library to convert the values in the tables to percents, but thus far I am unable to combine the results for Questions 1, 2, and 3 into 1 table.
The code I have written is:

```r
tableq1<-percent(table(Q1val)/length(na.omit(Q1val)))
tableq1
```

The current output is:

[image]

What do I need to do in order to achieve this?
Ultimately, I want to have this table as a pdf or png, with gridlines that make it look clean and professional.

Per request:

```
dput(Q1val)

c(4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 
4, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, NA, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 
4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 
4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 
4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 
4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5 # , ...
)
```

Comment: Do you have the data in variables `Q1val`, `Q2val`, and `Q3val`?

Comment: I do, they're each in the form of a double.

Comment: Then `allQ <- do.call(what = dplyr::bind_rows, args = sapply(X = list(Q1val, Q2val, Q3val), FUN = function(x) percent(table(x) / length(na.omit(x))), simplify = FALSE))` should get it into one table `allQ`.  Then `rownames(allQ) <- paste0("Q", 1:seq_len(nrow(allQ)))` should label the rows properly.

Comment: Hm, for some reason the allQ<-do.call(.....) results in a table like so: https://imgur.com/a/2s6RJma
The original code you posted created this table: 
https://imgur.com/a/gZViBaI
Which is more like what I need

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data by pasting the output from `dput(Q1val)`, `dput(Q2val)`, and `dput(Q3val)`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  This output should really go in your question post; and it should be pasted within code fences (``` ... ```).

Comment: Then the following code really should work: `allQ <- as.data.frame(do.call(what = dplyr::bind_rows, args = sapply(X = list(Q1val, Q2val, Q3val), FUN = function(x) percent(table(x) / length(na.omit(x))), simplify = FALSE))); rownames(allQ) <- paste0("Q", seq_len(nrow(allQ)))`.  It might have failed last time because I edited the comment while you were copying it.

Comment: This does!!!! Thank you so much for your help! Do you know of any way to make this into a pdf or png? I can also just screencap it, but I was hoping to hear from you if you prefer any methods to make a "pretty" table. Like with formattable or kable... Greg, thank you so much!

Comment: `gridExtra::grid.table(allQ)` should do it, where `grid.table()` is a function from the **`gridExtra`** package.  Specifically, the following code should render the table as `photo_of_allQ.png` and save it in your working directory: `grDevices::png("photo_of_allQ.png", height = 50 * nrow(allQ), width = 200 * ncol(allQ)); gridExtra::grid.table(allQ); grDevices::dev.off()`

Comment: Last question, I'd like to preserve the percentage formatting in the png generated. For some reason it's losing it, even though it is preserved in `allQ`

Comment: OK, so we should load the `dplyr` library and first transform the columns into text: `allQ <- allQ %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.character))`.  Then the rest of that rendering code should work as you desire.

Comment: Shall I just post this all as a solution?

Comment: Sure! Again, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an improvement over my comments, I've chosen to render the result with the [**`kableExtra`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtr) package.

## Solution

First load the appropriate packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
library(kableExtra)
```

Once you've generated the `Q*val` vectors in your workspace...

```
# ...
# Code to generate 'Q1val', 'Q2val', ...
# ...
```

...then run this workflow to consolidate them into a single contingency table:

```
# Identify all the 'Q*val' vectors.
q_names <- ls(pattern = "Q\\d+val")


# Assemble a single table.
q_all <- q_names %>%
  # Capture those vectors in a (named) list.
  mget(inherits = TRUE) %>%
  # Turn each vector into a contingency table of percentages.
  sapply(
    FUN = function(x) { 
      percent(table(x) / length(na.omit(x)))
    },
    simplify = FALSE
  ) %>%
  # Stack those contingency tables into a single table.
  do.call(what = bind_rows) %>%
  # Convert to 'data.frame' to preserve row names.
  as.data.frame() %>%
  # Add row names of "Q1", "Q2", ...; as extracted from the names "Q1val", "Q2val", ...
  `rownames<-`(value = gsub(
     x = q_names,
     pattern = "^(Q\\d+)(val)$",
     replacement = "\\1"
  ))
```

You can then prettify the table and export it as an image.

```
# Prettify the table.
q_pretty <- q_all %>%
  # Convert into 'kable' object.
  kbl() %>%
  # Border the rows and stripe the cells.
  kable_styling(
    bootstrap_options = c("bordered", "striped")
    
    # ...
    # Further styling as desired.
    # ...
    
  ) # %>%
  
  # ...
  # Further 'kable' adjustments as desired.
  # ...


# Save pretty table as PNG image.
save_kable(
  x = q_pretty,
  file = "pretty.png"
)
```

### Note

You can easily save as a PDF by replacing `"pretty.png"` with `"pretty.pdf"`.

## Result

I had to improvise my own `Q2val` and `Q3val`, but the resulting `pretty.png` should look like this:
[image: 2]